# How to get the name of layout associated with an activity in activity lifecycle onActivityStarted method?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I need to get layout name of any activity from activity life cycle method.

`override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) { Log.d("onActivityStarted", activity.localClassName) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this first get view group of your activity like this

```
val viewGroup = (activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
```

then get resources id and by the resources id get resources name like this

```
val resourceName = activity.resources.getResourceName(viewGroup.sourceLayoutResId)
```

thats it you have your attached layout path and name with your activity

```
Log.d("Layout res path", ">>>>>> $resourceName")
```

Comment: Thanks for comment

Comment: Ah, nice find. I'd forgotten that they've been adding stuff like that to `View` recently. However, `sourceLayoutResId` is only available starting with API level 29 (Q). Also, this is a little more involved than simply adding `private val layout = ...` to the `Activity` class. Just FYI. Cheers!